# How to interpolate link_to as a block

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, link-to

I'm trying to make a link_to block (link_to with do) within an interpolation for a helper that will be called many times, so i only want to have this code once in my project. But when i try to execute the code below i get the error "Unexpected keyword class, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('" so i don't know how to do this or if it's possible. The link_to block is between some html code and it's concatenated with it, that's why i need the html_safe at the bottom.

```
def example_helper_method()
  example_string = ""
  example_string += "SOME HTML ..."
  example_string += "#{ link_to edit_foo_url(param1, param2, param3: 1) do }"
  example_string += "<button class='btn btn-small #{foo_method(1)}' type='button'>Example</button>"
  example_string += "#{end}"
  example_string += "SOME HTML ..."
  return example_string.html_safe
end
```

Here is where i am calling this method in the view

```
<%= example_helper_method() %>
```

Thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`link_to` returns a string so why do you need all the interpolation? You'd want to turn the second string inside-out and move the `html_safe` call but something like this should do the trick:

```
def example_helper_method()
  example_string  = ''
  example_string += "SOME HTML ..."
  example_string += link_to edit_foo_url(param1, param2, param3: 1) do
    "<button class='btn btn-small #{foo_method(1)}' type='button'>Example</button>".html_safe
  end
  example_string + "SOME HTML..."
end
```

`link_to` should be returning something that is HTML-safe already so you don't need to `html_safe` what it returns. You do want an `html_safe` call inside the block as you're building HTML in a string. You may or may not need `html_safe` calls on the `SOME HTML` string depending on what's really there.

Comment: i forgot to say that the link_to block is between some html code and it's concatenated with it, that's why i use the html_safe at the bottom of the example_string.

Comment: Again, `link_to` just returns a string so there's no need for interpolation, just simple string concatenation with `html_safe` calls as needed is enough.

Comment: ooooh sorry, now i understand what your were talking about, yes your rigth, this is the way thanks :D